# Update Magento Products Memory Limit

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i have a script that updates or deletes products from magento, but i notice that consumes a lot of memory, i already get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php on line 852
```

So maybe the problem is with my script, maybe it must be optmized.

Steps that my script takes:

1- Make api call to get all products from our distribuitor

2- Get all Products from our store;

3- Loops are online store products collection;

4- On the iteration of each products searchs for the product inside the data from the api call, if exists the product it should update the stock and price, if doesnt exist it should delete the product since it doesnt exist.

Here is my code and maybe anybody can find what is wrong.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');

require 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                       ->addFieldToFilter(array(
                        array('attribute'=>'reference','neq'=>''),
));

//Get all Products API
$data = curlRequestObject("rest/catalog/products.xml?isoCode=pt");   

$productCollectionLength = count($productCollection);

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
try {
    $reference = $product->getReference();
    $res = $data->xpath("item/sku[.='{$reference}']/parent::*"); 

    //Product Info
    $productID = $res[0]->id;

    $price = $res[0]->retailPrice;

    if (count($res) <= 0){
       echo $product->getId() ." Deletec." . PHP_EOL;
       $product->delete();
       continue;
    }

    //Update Stock
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
    $stockAvailable = checkStock($productID);
    if ($stockItem->getId() > 0 and $stockItem->getManageStock()) {
      $qty = $stockAvailable;
      $stockItem->setQty($qty);
      $stockItem->setIsInStock((int)($qty > 0));
      $stockItem->save();
    }

    //Update Price
    $priceUpdate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $priceUpdate->setPrice($price);

    if($priceUpdate->getSpecialPrice() > $price){
      $priceUpdate->setSpecialPrice("");
    }
    $priceUpdate->save();

     echo $product->getReference() . PHP_EOL;

     } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        }
}

function curlRequestObject($api = "rest/catalog/category/2399.xml?isoCode=pt")
  {

    $ch = curl_init("http://api.domain.com/".$api);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
         'Authorization: Bearer hashasdada',
        'Accept: text/plain'
      ));

      $data = curl_exec($ch);

      curl_close($ch);

      $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement( $data );

      return $oXML;



  }

  function checkStock($id = 0)
  {

   /* if($id === 0){
      return http_response_code(404);
    }*/
    $api = "rest/catalog/productstock/".$id.".xml?isoCode=pt";
    $ch = curl_init("http://api.domain.com/".$api);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
         'Authorization: Bearer dasdsa',
        'Accept: text/plain'
      ));

      $data = curl_exec($ch);

      curl_close($ch);

      $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement( $data );

      return $oXML->stocks->quantity;



  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods like **load** and **save** on product model ('catalog/product') consume a lot of memory.(and fire some events)

since you are iterating through a product collection ('catalog/product_collection') anyway, you may add your getter attributes to collection query by

```js
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('reference')
            ->addFieldToFilter(array(
                        array('attribute'=>'reference','neq'=>''),
));
```

this way you can get rid of

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
```

and just use $product model object from collection

secondly you will boost the whole thing by replacing

```
$priceUpdate->setPrice($price);
$priceUpdate->save();
```

with

```
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'price');
```

and same with special_price

Enable and run **Product Flat Data**, this will speed up collection performance if you have a lot of attributes and under 100k products

Comment: Thanks, and for the " Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')" is there any update i should make?

Comment: cataloginventory model has much better performance, there is not much you can do about it. in case of hardcore optimization you may save data with plain mysql queries. But that is an overkill, and won't make a lot of difference.

Comment: Thanks, i made the script and is running, but i need to find a faster way, because for example i have in my case 15000 products on the 'catalog/product_collection', and in this iterating im checking on the "$data" api of the product exists and check for changes on prices, and stock (api call check stock status), all this is taking me more than 3 hours to process, need to find a better way :S

Comment: i can't really judge what part of your script consumes most time. maybe api calls or parsing of large xml result objects. you should measure micro time for each part of the script to see where optimization is most necessary

Comment: in case my answer helped you with initial problem of memory consumption you may accept or upvote. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can update memory limit for your script by setting unlimited memory are as follows.

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1); // Add this line in your starting part of the script.
```